# UWP List Assets Files

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to view the files in my "Assets" folder.  I can see if one file is there because it won't allow me to add it again. However, I want to see all of the files in the debugger but I get the following error:

"To inspect the native object, enable native code debugging."

Here is the code I'm trying to debug/inspect.

```
StorageFolder appInstalledFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFolder assets1 = await appInstalledFolder.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var files = await assets1.GetFilesAsync();
```

I've added the following code but still getting the Native code error.

```
StorageFolder folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
// StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var options = new QueryOptions();
options.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");//this will add .csv files to query options 
options.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;//optional
StorageFileQueryResult query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await query.GetFilesAsync();
```

error from debugger:  To inspect the native object, enable native code debugging.

Comment: Unable to reproduce your issue, try clean and rebuild solution or launch in release mode

Answer (score 1):

This is reproducible by hovering mouse over the variable when debugging:

[image: Reproduction of the error]

The reason for this error is the fact that the returned instance is not a classic .NET type but a projection of a native WinRT list into .NET. The proof of this Visual Studio displays just `System.__ComObject` instead of a type. However, this type acts as a `IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>` so you can use it as a list even though it is a native type.

If you want to be able to see the contents in the debugger, you will need to manually convert it to a purely .NET type, for example using `ToArray` LINQ extension method:

```
var files = 
    (await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync())
    .ToArray();
```

This will make `files` a regular .NET array, which is fully inspectable by the debugger.

[image: Debugger now displays data]